# React Navigation's navigate() function doesn't work

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-component, react-dom

I am Building an application using React Native and the **React Navigation** library.

#### Steps to reproduce the issue

So using React Navigation 5, I built a stack navigator with two screens as follows:

```tsx
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Nav = () => {
  <Stack.Navigator
    <Stack.Screen
        name="A"
        component={A}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
        name="B"
        component={B}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
}
```

As the screen **A** is the first in the navigator, it will be the first to be shown and rendered on screen. Now I want to immediately navigate to **B** As soon as **A** has rendered, so I wrote the following code in **A**:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    navigation.navigate('B');
}, [navigation]);
```

#### The problem

The problem is that the screen stays stuck in **A** and doesn't navigate to **B**

#### Possible cause

I think that when the screen **A** tried to execute its `useEffect` code, the screen **B** still hasn't been loaded into the DOM of the navigator. Because when I actually tried to delay the execution of the `useEffect` by 2 seconds like this:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
        navigation.navigate('B');
    }, 2000)
}, [navigation]);
```

and it worked, the screen navigated from **A** to **B**! So I suppose that **B** had the time to be loaded into the DOM in less than 2 seconds ?

#### Any solution ?

So, if my assumption is right, I was wondering whether there is a formal way of checking if the screen **B** has been effectively loaded into the DOM of the navigator, or maybe waiting until the navigator has rendered before executing `useEffect` in **A**. Maybe there's a special react hook or library to check this kind of conditions ?

And if I'm wrong please help me !

Comment: hi..did you get the solution for this issue ?

Comment: I am experiencing something similar, the initial `navigate` call in a `useEffect()` hook doesn't work, but later on it does! I am also using a `useIsFocused()` hook to check that the navigator is in fact focused when the `navigate` gets called.

Answer (score 1):

I think the navigation does not work because you didn't wrap your stack screens into the stack navigator like this:

```tsx
<Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
        name="A"
        component={A}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
        name="B"
        component={B}
    />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

This is shown in the [navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation#creating-a-stack-navigator)

Comment: Sorry I just forgot <Stack.Navigator /> in the code above, but it is there in the app. And the navigation works perfectly when I trigger it with a button.